# How to detect changes in directories or file inside that directory using php

Tags: php, directory, directory-structure

I have directory structure like this:

```
    [Products] => Array
        (
            [Category1] => Array
                (
                    [product1] => Array
                        (
                           [documents] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Attachment1.pdf
                                    [1] => Attachment2.pdf
                                )
            )
        )
    )
```

if there is any changes in any directory or file inside products directory
like:

1. product1 changed to product2
2. new directory added
3. any changes in file Attachment.pdf
4. new document added to directory.

What i have tried till now:

```
$dir="PATH TO PRODUCT DIRECTORY"
$stats = stat($dir);
```

but $stats['mtime'] detected change in Products children only (Like if change Category1 to Category2 or newly added directory to products) but not in grand children of products (Like if i change product1 to product2) and so on.

Can any one help me to delect any changes in product with children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution i have implemented. By using these function i am able to get a MD5 hash code and i can use this hash code to check if there is any changes in directory structure or in any file.

```
        $dir="PATH TO PRODUCT DIRECTORY";
        public function directoryHash($dir, $item_name){
            $dirStr=$this->directoryStruture($dir, $separator= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $root='');
            $strHash=md5(json_encode($dirStr));
            return $strHash;
        }

        public function directoryStruture($dir, $separator = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $root = '') {
            $result = array();

            $cdir = scandir($dir);
            $result = array();
            if ($root === '') {
                $root = $dir;
            }
            $cdir = scandir($dir);
            foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {

                if (!in_array($value, array(".", ".."))) {
                    $current = $dir . $separator . $value;
                    if (is_dir($current)) {
                        $result['items'][] = $value;
                        $result[$value] = $this->directoryStruture($current, $separator, $root);
                    } else {
                        $filePath = str_replace($root, '', $current);
                        $result[] = $filePath.filemtime($current);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }
```

If there is any better approach. Please let me know.

Thanks,

M.